# Why Didn't Hughie Kill A-Train When He Had the Chance?

Tags: the-boys, the-boys-2019

In the Amazon Prime show, *The Boys*, the whole point of Hughie joining the team is to get revenge on A-Train for:

> Killing his girlfriend Robin

and really just to kill Supes in general.

However, in the 7th episode, when Kimiko

> Breaks A-Train's leg, rendering him helpless,

Hughie doesn't seem interested at all in finishing A-Train off, or even in taking any further action to protect his father. Why is that? We know that he's capable of willfully killing people. Why wouldn't he get what he's wanted since episode 1? A-Train has also made many serious threats against Hughie and his family. I feel like the show kinda glossed over the fact that they had a golden opportunity to off one of The Seven, but didn't take it for no apparent reason.

Comment: As explained in the dialog, A-Train made the argument that everything he did was accidental and everything Hughie did was willful.

Comment: But that dialog came after that episode, in the warehouse. Hughie would not have had that perspective yet.

Comment: @jared.nesbit  No. Watch it again and you will see that Kimiko is able to sneak up and attack A-train because he is emotionally saying the lines that Pop is talking about.

Comment: You're right! I thought that came later. That explains a lot.